# 404 after transfer from old server to new server in WHM

Tags: cpanel, whm

I've just transferred a domain from one WHM/cpanel server to another newly setup server. I used the WHM transfer function, which seems great. The transfer went fine. No errors.  When I click the new domain's IP in the List Accounts section of WHM, the preview comes back as a 404.

Comment: There's really quite a few things that could result in a `404` error (e.g., account setup issues, DNS setup issues, redirect issues...). There's really no way for us to be able to tell other than taking guesses, which is not a good fit for this site - in general we don't troubleshoot individual sites. You can see some related questions [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=404+cpanel+is%3Aq). You should also take a look at your error logs to see what's occurring, as well as your [transfer logs](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/68Docs/Review+Transfers+and+Restores).

Comment: Perhaps the following question might be of help:  [404 when accessing website from IP address on VPS](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/99621/404-when-accessing-website-from-ip-address-on-vps).

Comment: I heard from my dedicated server provider: The feature to use a "temporary URL" with IP/~username is no longer supported by default in cPanel.  So I had to setup the IP/domain in my local machine's hosts file. I didn't have anything setup incorrectly.

Comment: I see, so you added IP/domain for your server per the link in my comment above and that resolved the issue for you?

Comment: Hi Dan. I didn't see your link. I did what my provider suggested, but looks to be the same solution!